# O que devo retornar em um HttpPost e HttpPut em uma API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Estou fazendo uma API em .NET Core e me surgiu uma dúvida no que devo retornar nos métodos HttpPost e HttPut, conforme abaixo:

```
    // POST: api/Product
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] ProductDto product)
    {
        try
        {
            await _productAppService.Add(product);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex);
        }
    }

    // PUT: api/Product/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(Guid id, [FromBody] ProductDto product)
    {
        try
        {
            var success = await _productAppService.Update(id, product);
            return success ? Ok() : (IActionResult)NotFound();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex);
        }
    }
```

Como podem ver, ao efetuar um POST eu retorno simplesmente um OK e ao efetuar um PUT, caso ele encontre o ID de um produto, ele me retorna OK, caso contrário, retorna NotFound.

Visando as melhores práticas, o que seria necessário retornar nesses métodos? Como por exemplo uma flag de sucesso e a model recém armazenada, ou um simples OK já basta? ou isso depende do contexto em que estamos trabalhando?

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O return type de uma API muitas vezes é negligenciado, apesar de ter tanta importância quanto qualquer outra parte.

O retorno de cada endpoint depende do que exatamente é feito pela API. No caso de um `POST` o mais normal é utilizar o `201 Created` (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2) e incluir o `Location` do registro recém criado. No seu caso isso é fácil fazer isso com o método `CreatedAtAction`.

Em alguns casos, onde a ação não é interpretada imediatamente, o mais correto é utilizar o `202 Accepted` (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3). Este comportamento é mais usual em sistemas mais sofisticados, onde a ação não é interpretada pela API.

No caso do `PUT` não faz sentido retornar um `created`, tampouco informar o URI da entidade, uma vez que este já é conhecido. Sendo assim, o mais usual é retornar o `204 No content` (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5). Assim como no `POST`, também pode fazer sentido retornar o `202 Accepted`.

A documentação da Microsoft é uma boa fonte de informações sobre como construir uma API com C#: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Vai depender mais do que você está precisando no seu contexto, mas normalmente para **POST** uma boa prática é retornar um **201 (Created)** com o link para o objeto. Já para **PUT** você pode retornar um **204 (No content)**.

Para mais informações, de uma lida nesses links:

https://solidgeargroup.com/best-practices-rest-api/

https://restfulapi.net/http-status-201-created/

https://restfulapi.net/http-status-204-no-content/